# Find subword included input symbol c++

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic, conditional-statements, substring

I want to print a subword, after inputting my symbol.
For example like this.

I want input `abcdefghijk   d`

And get `efghijk`

This is my code body without condition.

```
   #include <iostream>

   int main(){
   const int n = 21;
   char word[n];
   std::cin>>word;
   char symbol;
   std::cin>>symbol;
   int i = 0;
   char*p = word;
   while(word[i]!='\0' && word[i]!=symbol){
   // what condition I need to write here?
   i++;
   std::cout << p <<std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
  }
```

Thanks for helping))

Comment: One of the 1st thing you should learn as a beginner in c++ is, that text is represented as `std::string` type and not `char*`. This will make some operations like simply comparing two `std::string` variables simple as `s1 == s2` or `s1 == "hello"`.

Comment: BTW, don't use tabs when posting to StackOverflow; use spaces for indentation.

Comment: Also using `std::cin` into an array is dangerous because `std::cin` doesn't know the capacity of the array, so it is possible to overflow.  Use `std::getline` and `std::string` or use a loop for the array.

Comment: Reminder:  if you are using C-style strings, reserve an extra slot in the array for the terminating nul character.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move your pointer p to the right while the splitting character is not met.

```
char*p = word;
while(word[i]!='\0' && word[i]!=symbol){
    p++;
    i++;
}
p++;
std::cout << p << std::endl;
```

On the first line, your pointer p points to the begining of the word (i.e. on the first char).
Then the while loop tests every char until we find the splitting char. Everytime a character does not match you splitting character, you increase p and make it point to the next character.

However, you would need to increase it one final time after the loop to point *after* the splitting char.

Note that a shorter way to do is:

```
char*p = word;
while(word[i]!='\0' && word[i]!=symbol){
    i++;
}
p = p + i + 1;
std::cout << p << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
int main()
{
    std::string text;
    std::cout << "Enter sentence: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, text);
    char  split_char;  
    std::cout << "Enter subword / split character: ";
    std::cin >> split_char;

    std::string::size_type split_position = text.find(split_char);
    std::string::size_type word_end_position = text.find_first_of(" \t", split_position);
    if (word_end_position == std::string::npos)
    {
        word_end_position = text.length();
    }
    std::string split_text = text.substr(split_position, word_end_position, split_position);
    std::cout << split_text << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```